# Adding UUID to response/request in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for a way to accept a rest api request in asp.net Web Api and add a UUID for each request, just before logging that same request.

Furthermore that same UUID should also be present in my response in order to be able to match request and response when analyzing logs.

Since I am using JSON as an output format and it is not possible to use comments in JSON compared to XML where yu I could have

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<!-- uuid:aaaef973-d8ce-4c92-95b4-3635bb2d42d5 -->
```

My questions is what would be a good way to add UUID when handling request/response in JSON format.

Also, since I am not sure is it a better idea to do this on a controller or handler level, is  there an existing solution or nuget that already adds UUID to request/response?

Comment: If you need that just for logging, why add it to response itself (I mean to what will actually be sent to caller)? Caller doesn't care about that as I understand.

Comment: @Evk how would you match request x with response y later on in logs?

Comment: Depends on how you log them

Comment: @Evk how would you have a client report a problem with a request. Maybe you logic fails to detect a problem, maybe your client would say request: aaaef973-d8ce-4c92-95b4-3635bb2d42d5 returns an unexpected output. If he has not Id you could not connect it with an issue

Comment: But in that case, shouldn't caller provide id in request? For example, client makes a request for non-existing file and 404 is returned, where would you place that uuid?

Comment: @Evk 404 is outside of a business-error scope.

Comment: Ok, what if use custom header? `X-Request-ID` or something like that, and pass uuid there?

Comment: That is one of the possibility, but I read a lot of comments where headers can fail to process due to different clients